# Как работать с SIP?

Tags: java, sip

Какие есть библиотеки сторонние или возможно официальные для работы с IP телефонией в Ява? Необходимо написать приложение которое будет давать вызов на указанный номер (тоже ip телефония). Всё находиться в одном домене, логины, порты, сервера настроены и работают. IP телефоны тоже работают. Но вот возникла задача набирать номер с ПК. Что посоветуете? Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Посмотрите вот [сюда](https://github.com/mikekwright/sip-softphone) Это то что вы ищете?

Comment: Нет, это не то к сожалению.

Answer (score 0):

Я работал с библиотекой PJSIP http://www.pjsip.org/  У нее есть "обертка" для Java https://sourceforge.net/projects/pjsip-jni/  При наборе номера номер передается просто в виде строки.